# Problem with seeding my many-many EF relationships in Code First Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been having a problem with updating my migration. I am able to generate the migration just fine. I learned these techniques for seeding the database from the book *C# 10 and .NET 6* by Mark J. Price. I have applied the techniques that I learned, although incorrectly as it may seem, while following along with IAmTimCorey's Suggestion Site App Playlist on YouTube. He uses MongoDB, but I have chosen to use SQL Server with EF Core. I have a few one-to-one relationships but this one many-many relationship that I highlighted below is throwing the error.

SuggestionModel.cs

```
[Key]
public long SuggestionId { get; set; }
...
public ICollection<UserModel> UserVotes { get; set; } = new HashSet<UserModel>();
...
```

UserModel.cs

```
[Key]
public long UserId { get; set; }
...
public ICollection<SuggestionModel> VotedOnSuggestions { get; set; } = new List<SuggestionModel>();
...
```

DbConnection.cs (DbContext class)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   ...
   modelBuilder.Entity<UserModel>().HasData(user1, user2, user3, user4);
   modelBuilder.Entity<SuggestionModel>().HasData(suggestion1, suggestion2, suggestion3, suggestion4, suggestion5);
   modelBuilder.Entity<SuggestionModel>().HasMany(s => s.UserVotes).WithMany(u => u.VotedOnSuggestions)
        .UsingEntity(e => e.HasData(
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 4L, UserVotesUserId = 1L },
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 4L, UserVotesUserId = 2L },
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 4L, UserVotesUserId = 3L },
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 5L, UserVotesUserId = 1L },
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 5L, UserVotesUserId = 2L },
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 5L, UserVotesUserId = 3L },
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 5L, UserVotesUserId = 4L }
            ));
}
```

The exact error

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
'FK_SuggestionModelUserModel_Users_UserVotesUserId' on table 'SuggestionModelUserModel'
may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO
ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

SQL Command that caused the error

```
 Failed executing DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text',
 CommandTimeout='30']
 CREATE TABLE [SuggestionModelUserModel] ( 
 [UserVotesUserId] bigint NOT NULL,
 [VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId] bigint NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT 
 [PK_SuggestionModelUserModel] PRIMARY KEY ([UserVotesUserId], 
 [VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId]),
 CONSTRAINT [FK_SuggestionModelUserModel_Suggestions_VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId] 
 FOREIGN KEY ([VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId]) REFERENCES [Suggestions] 
 ([SuggestionId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT [FK_SuggestionModelUserModel_Users_UserVotesUserId] FOREIGN KEY 
 ([UserVotesUserId]) REFERENCES [Users] ([UserId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
 );
```

EDIT:
The only thing that I changed in my code that was different from what I learned was that I initialize both UserVotes and VotedOnSuggestions as different collections. UserVotes has to be a HashSet and VotedOnSuggestions must be a List

Comment: I am asking a question regarding a many-many relationship and you sent me to a question asking about a one-many relationship. How does this help? None of the methods available to solving the cascading deletion problem exist for the many-many relationship.

Comment: SQL server doesn't have a many-many join. Its equivalent to 2x 1-many joins. The solution is the same. Plus the problem is probably related to other foreign keys in your model that you have not included in your question.